# Unzipping file without first directory

Tags: linux, perl

I want to extract some files. Ex. test.zip to /path/to/folder. Using Archive::Extract and specifying a "to" in extract I can extract it to /path/to/folder, but it extracts to /path/to/folder/test. Same goes for using the system unzip/gunzip.

I don't want to unzip -j, I want to keep the subdirectories.

Is there a way to do this that does not involve browsing to /path/to/folder/test and cp -rf * ../? Either by system command or in perl...

Thanks for reading. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might prefer [`Archive::Zip`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Archive%3a%3aZip#%24zip-%3EextractTree%28_%24root%2C_%24dest%2C_%24volume_%29)

```
Archive::Zip->new( 'test.zip' )->extractTree( '', '/path/to/folder' );
```